# the bot considers all server members offline except itself

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to setup servers stats with my bot. I noticed a problem that bot says that user is offline even he's online. I have Intents so I don't know what can cause this problem. [using comman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOGmt.png) [user is online!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkB09.png)

Here are Intents:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
```

And command 'status':

```
@bot.command()
async def status(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(member.status)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's because that needs `presences` intent not `members` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.presences

Comment: I don't know haw to answer a comment, BUT THANKS A LOT DUDE!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I should use presences Intents with members Intents! The question is closed